# create custom decorator for views that check if user is blacklisted

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to create a decorator for my views that checks the DB if the user has over or equal to 5 warnings, and if so then I redirect him to a page telling him he has been flagged etc.

I wrote the code for it but I want to pass the request object to the decorator so I can call request.user for db queries but that doesn't seem like it's possible. How would I go on about this?

Decorator:

```
def check_blacklist(request):
    try:
        db = blacklist.objects.get(user=request.user)
        warnings = db.warning
        if warnings >= 5:
            return redirect("security:flagged")
    except:
        pass
```

models.py

```
class blacklist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    warning = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
@check_blacklist(request)
def task_info(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/task.html',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that :

1. Use `@app.before_request` decorator to trap everything before it reachs your router
2. Define your blacklist fonction to be called before every request
3. Use `request` object, as it's global

It should give your something like this (not tested):

```
@app.before_request
def check_blacklist():
    if must_check_blacklist(request.endpoint):
        try:
           db = blacklist.objects.get(user=request.user)
           warnings = db.warning
           if warnings >= 5:
               return redirect("security:flagged")
        except:
           pass
```

Comment: From a quick google search - Isn't `@app.before_request` a thing from flask? Also where does `must_check_blacklist` come from?

Comment: You are right, I didn't see that your post was about django... As for ´must_check_blacklist´ it is just a placeholder method to filter which requested endpoint you want to apply your condition

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to call the decorator directly in your `urls.py` file (it is possible, and I'm doing it for something similar to your usecase). This is what I would do for instance:

```py
# decorators.py

def check_blacklist():
    def decorator_fun(func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            my_user = request.user
            called_func = func(request, *args, **kwargs)            
            # your stuff goes here
            return called_func
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator_fun
```

```py
# urls.py

from app.decorators import check_blacklist
urlpatterns = [
        path('your_url', check_blacklist()(your_view.as_view()), name='your_view'),
]
```

Hope that helps!